# pipe output of gzip into csplit

Tags: unix, pipe, csplit

This command works:

```
csplit really_big_file.txt -f ../dump/really_big_file_ /^H\|756\|/ {*}
```

but this command:

```
gzip -dc  really_big_file.txt.gz | csplit -f ../dump/really_big_file_ /^H\|756\|/ {*}
```

yields:

```
csplit: cannot open '/^H|756|/' for reading: No such file or directory
```

How to pipe output of gzip into csplit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `man csplit` it says that file always  comes before pattern:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    csplit [OPTION]... FILE PATTERN...
> ```

So it should be:

```
gzip -dc  really_big_file.txt.gz | csplit -f ../dump/really_big_file_ - /^H\|756\|/ {*}
```

Example:

```
$ gzip -dc inputfile.txt.gz
abc
searchstring
def
searchstring
egh
searchstring
$ mkdir split
$ gzip -dc inputfile.txt.gz | csplit  -f split/file - /searchstring/ {*}
$ ls -Al split/
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users  4 Sep 21 17:53 file00
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 17 Sep 21 17:53 file01
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 17 Sep 21 17:53 file02
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 13 Sep 21 17:53 file03
$ cat split/*
abc
searchstring
def
searchstring
egh
searchstring
```

Comment: Sorry but your command after 'it should be' is exactly identical to the one in my question. Is there a typo there?

Comment: @user189035: yes, sorry, I forgot `-` to denote standard input.